# Amazon Alexa SetVolume Directive

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to implement the Alexa.Speaker interface with the Node.js v2 sdk.

When testing, I always get the output: `There was a problem with the requested skill's response` and this error in my CloudWatch logs:

```
{
    "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
    "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.bf854d70-70c1-4e7f-b2b0-76c4574244a5",
    "timestamp": "2018-10-22T16:58:12Z",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "reason": "ERROR",
    "error": {
        "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
        "message": "An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."
    }
}
```

Here's my code.

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .addDirective({
        type: 'Alexa.Speaker',
        name: 'SetVolume',
        payload: {
            volume: volume,
        },
        token: 'correlationToken',
    })
    .getResponse();
```

I've implemented the Connections.SendRequest interface in this way before, so I'm not sure what's wrong/different with Alexa.Speaker.

Comment: I recommend you put a breakpoint just before you execute the addDirective call and make sure the values are correct.   Is 'volume' initialized?  is the token correct?

Comment: Yes, volume is passed in correctly and the token: 'correlationToken' is what the Connections.SendRequest documentation specifies (I can't find documentation specifically for Alexa.Speaker).

Comment: Your request looks a bit different that their docs for setVolume:  https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-speaker.html#setvolume.  Are you sure you are setting it up correctly?